# Entity Framework Migrations: error on web server only

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid

I am using Entity Framework Code-First Migrations and everything is great locally.

My DB is SQLServer 2008. (Also using SQL CE for local development)
I can use the live SQL Server db connection string locally with no problem.

Here is the Migration code in _appStart.cshtml:

```
@using EF = System.Data.Entity;
@using TCommon = Told.Web.Common.Logic;
@{
    // Manually initialize
    var initializer = new EF.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TCommon.CommonContext, TCommon.Migrations.Configuration>();
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
    initializer.InitializeDatabase(new TCommon.CommonContext());

    // DB Maintenance
    TCommon.AppUserLogic.CleanDatabase();

    // Asp.Net
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ToldDB", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);

    // Common
    TCommon.AppStart.Run();
}
```

This works great locally. Either against a SQL CE or against my live database. It ran fine locally to migrate my live database to the latest version.

However, when I put it on my web server, it throws this exception:

### Exception

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

[MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() +8566285
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +181
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +211
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders) +295
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XDocumentExtensions.GetStoreItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo) +180
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString) +48
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration) +55
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +269
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +456
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +64
```

Now, this has something to do with the migration attempt. So when I wrap the migration call in a try-catch block, I can use the database fine (because I migrated the live db locally).

```
@using EF = System.Data.Entity;
@using TCommon = Told.Web.Common.Logic;
@{
    // Manually initialize
    var initializer = new EF.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TCommon.CommonContext, TCommon.Migrations.Configuration>();
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
    try
    {
        initializer.InitializeDatabase(new TCommon.CommonContext());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    var db = new TCommon.CommonContext();
    var test = db.AppUsers.FirstOrDefault();

    // DB Maintenance
    TCommon.AppUserLogic.CleanDatabase();

    // Asp.Net
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ToldDB", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);

    // Common
    TCommon.AppStart.Run();
}
```

What would be causing the migration diff-check to fail when I try to run it on my web server?

---

#### Edit:

Here is the web.config for the Entity Framework:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  ...
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true"  />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ToldDB" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using the same web.config file on your web server as on your dev box? It seems like your ADO.NET provider whose invariant name is specified as the manifest token in your SSDL is not registered on the web server. You can get the manifest token by using EF PowerTools or by executing EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(). Check if the name is specified either in your web.config or (especially for SqlServer) in machine.config.

Comment: I am using an identical web.config (when using the live DB locally). I will add all my web.config parts that concern the Entity Framework in my question.

Comment: By the way, I am using Code-First POCO. I have not used any designer. My Classes are in a class library where I generated the Migrations using Nuget Package Manager add-migration. Everything with the class library is working great. Even the entities are working, just not the migration.

Comment: Do you have Sql Server CE installed on the web server. I have a feeling that since you mixed providers EF is trying to use Sql Server CE on the server and it's not installed there. Not sure how this could happen and what it really means in the greater scheme of things.

Comment: I haven't found any answers for this. I am just manually updating the db before I deploy right now.

Comment: Hi! I have been working on the exact same problem for about 10 hours now. Everything works on my local box, but on windows azure websites it fails, but only the first request! It also fails to seed data after the migration, but the migration itself works. I am leaning towards this being a problem with EF5 trying to find SQL CE.

Comment: I added a bounty to this now.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the answer:
Make sure that you install these nuget-packages:
Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact and 
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact

Deploy again, and make sure that SQL Server CE is now in the \bin-folder (the folders x86 and amd64 with all the files).
And also these files must be in the bin-folder:
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll

Make sure it is the right version. The ones that are installed with SQL Ce did not work, it must be the ones from the nuget package.

Also make sure the Web.config contains this:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

And this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Note that you have to do this no matter if you use SqlCE on the production server. I am not sure you need the bin-files for the database itself, though.